# Spring MVC back end ajax validation

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring

For my current project Java/Spring project I have to validate a form. The webpage is a freemarker template file.

The `<form>` has no special attribute to send the data to the controller. The project uses Ajax to send the request. The controller doesn't receive the form at all.

When the user submits the data, a JavaScript function is called to receive all the data by collecting the elementID's. The data is put in a variable, like this (short version);

```
var userId = document.getElementById('input_id').value.toLowerCase();
var width = document.getElementById("width");
var height = document.getElementById("height");
```

The function then puts all the `data` into a JSON. This JSON is put in the Ajax, and then Ajax calls the right controller.

**Ajax code **

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json", // expected format for response
        contentType: "application/json", // send as JSON
        Accept: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            // we have the response
            if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
                console.log("succes");
                //Redirect to the right page if the user has been saved successfully
                if (type === "setupuser") {
                    window.location = "/setup/user/" + userId;
                } else if (type === "simulatoruser") {
                    window.location = "/simulator/user/" + userId;
                }
            } else {
                errorInfo = "";
                for (i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
                    errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) + ". " + response.result[i].code;
                }
                $('#error').html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
                $('#info').hide('slow');
                $('#error').show('slow');
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
```

The following controller is called by the Ajax request:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/adduser/{userType}")
@ResponseBody
JsonResponse addUserMapping(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user, BindingResult result, @RequestBody String jsonString, @PathVariable String userType) {

    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
    String userId = json.userId
    String userName = json.userName

    user.setId(userId)
    user.setName(userName)

    log.warn("User id..... "+user.getId())
    log.warn("User name..... "+user.getName())

    JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "id", "userId can not be empty.");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "name", "userName can not be empty");


    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        userService.addUser(jsonString)
        res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    }else{
        res.setStatus("FAIL");
        res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
    }

    return res;
}
```

As you can see, Ajax sends a JSON to the controller. The controller unpacks the JSON and puts the data into the user object. Then the user object is being validated using `"rejectIfEmpty()"`  method...

Now I've been reading about making a `userValidator` class extending `Validator`, or simply putting Annotations in the bean class like:

```
@Size(min=1, max=3)
```

I prefer these annotations since you don't have to write special code for checking certain simple things (like the field not being empty .. `@NotEmpty`)

But that doesn't work because the controller doesn't take a user object the second it's called, instead it takes the JSON and then unpacks it (Validating is too late..)

TL:DR

Controller takes a JSON as a parameter instead of an Object. The JSON has to be unpacked and then validated in the controller as a java object using `rejectIfEmpty` as an example. I don't want a full page reload, but I still want to keep Ajax.

BTW: I want to validate the data against more things like regex etc. But the rejectifEmpty is a simple example.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the validation by parsing the JSON in the controller and setting it in the user object. The user object is then put in my UserValidator class and validated.

Link for more info using the validator:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html